# Running long commands in powershell

Tags: shell, powershell

I need to run a `curl` command on a container running in `kubernetes` cluster via `PowerShell`. Now, with `curl`, i need to pass various headers containing long token `Strings`. However, when i execute the command, the command string gets split in midway and terminal enters into newline mode from which I am not able to exit.

Below is the command.

```
curl -X GET http://sit-product-abcd-xyzx-adapter:8080/prdcopy/projects/PROJECT-NOVEMBER2020-eCom-SPORT_STYLE-3 -H "authorization: bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IlhSQVFGbGs3V0tNWnFzRm1ZUDcxaE55U3c4TSIsImtpZCI6IlhSQVFGbGs3V0tNWnFzRm1ZUDcxaE55U3c4TSJ9.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.kBrQO48rK_lkhDeZIQkW_If9lcYn5kERiif1VtlcXAPQ_j94KDGTfrmvF9f89EeyzExZSHFnCx0HyI8tvpeklEypWGchI4qG8V8z-AjTBrmKnX6mMSVLYaoh0TsLdeaFX-ByQ4TmyXzt5jje-CcS62w8P1J3aalVNhlTUp9e5rtP9qpttu2QmA482anQSsS6GN6ltJY9NyjfrW-ElZRrPXunIAf16jOjG0ehEUS8GpUJnc-wStJnF_zYuvnb-4m2GqzXqDHtpEvojg5N0Luq07z2mMpeEXbrGx-0fScjkSAsCJ8E-sFpbBYSXOCHfCslUPjM07kyzaZaa9tgWJGrGA" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "content-type: application/json" -H "project-id-type: API"
```

However, when i enter this command in power-shell after entering into the container, it looks like below.

```
PS R:\> kubectl exec -it sit-pcapi-order-event-consumer-b6f4c8797-m578d -- sh
/opt/app # curl -X GET http://sit-product-abcd-xyzx-adapter:8080/prdcopy/projects/PROJECT-NOVEMBER2020-eCom-SPORT_STYLE-
3 -H "authorization: bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IlhSQVFGbGs3V0tNWnFzRm1ZUDcxaE55U3c4TSIsImtpZCI6
IlhSQVFGbGs3V0tNWnFzRm1ZUDcxaE55U3c4TSJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi5hcGkuYWRpZGFzLmNvbS9jb3JwbWFya2V0L3ByZGNvcHkiLCJpc3M
iOiJodHRwOi8vc3RzLXRlc3QuYWRpZGFzLWdyb3VwLmNvbS9hZGZzL3NlcnZpY2VzL3RydXN0IiwiaWF0IjoxNTYzOTUyOTI5LCJuYmYiOjE1NjM5NTI5Mjk
sImV4cCI6MTU2Mzk1NjUyOSwic3ViIjoic3ZjX3BjYXBpIiwiZGlzdGluZ3Vpc2hlZG5hbWUiOiJDTj1zdmNfcGNhcGksT1U9U2VydmljZUFjY291bnRzLE9
VPVVzZXJzLE9VPUVNQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRpb24sREM9ZW1lYSxEQz1h456bnQsREM9Yml6IiwiYXBwdHlwZSI6IkNvbmZpZGVudGlhbCIsImFwcGlkIjoiNTA4
NzM2YTAtNzM5Mi00ODBkLTlmYWQtYWQ5NzUwMDI3ZjVhIiwiYXV0aG1ldGhvZCI6InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDphYzpjbGFzc2VzOlBh
c3N3b3JkUHJvdGVjdGVkVHJhbnNwb3J0IiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoiMjAxOS0wNy0yNFQwNzoyMjowOS43NTFaIiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwic2NwIjoidXNlcl9p
bXBlcnNvbmF0aW9uIG9wZW5pZCJ9.kBrQO48rK_lkhDeZIQkW_If9lcYn5kERiif1VtlcXAPQ
>
>
>
```

After this, i need to close the terminal and re-login into the container and kill the sh process manually.

How can i exit this curl command in power-shell? How can i execute long curl commands? I tried `powershell_ise`, but in that, i am not able to execute `kubectl exec` command. After executing that command, the terminal remains stuck forever.

Comment: Did you try loading the long string from a file and passing it to `curl` as a variable?  Similarly, you could save your command as a script, with the various parameters defined as variables, then assemble the command using these.

Comment: Will try using variable. But we cant execute the scripts. Script execution is somehow restricted on the machine. I am not sure how they did that.

Comment: Did you check the [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can copy the token as file into the container/pod and then pass it to curl as file.

More or less like this:

```
# Copy file
kubectl cp /tmp/token namespace/sit-pcapi-order-event-consumer-b6f4c8797-m578d:/tmp/token

# Pass the token as file instead of literal
kubectl exec -it sit-pcapi-order-event-consumer-b6f4c8797-m578d -- sh /opt/app # curl -X GET http://.../ -H @header_file $URL
```

Regards